# Why isn't my web page displaying the time (javaScript)

Tags: javascript, html

Hey guys in my head I have linked the java script file

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Tech News</title>
    <link href="layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type ="text/javascript" src=" script.ja"> </script>
```

and in the java script file I have this code

```
window.onload = initDate;

function initDate()
{
    now = new Date();

    localtime = now.toString();
    globaltime = now.toGMTString();

    document.write("<b> Local time: </b> " + localtime + "<br>");

    hours = now.getHours();
    mins = now.getMinutes();
    secs = now.getSeconds();

    document.write ("<font size = '+1'>");
    document.write(hours + ":" + mins +":" + secs);
    document.write("</font>");

    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = dtString;
}
```

Now this code should display the string in thie div tag but it doesn't

```
    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = dtString;
```

Here is the div tag.

```
            <div id="time"> <!--Time-->

            </div>
```

My website is 100& verified with no coding errors, both HTML and CSS.

So what will be the problem?

Comment: What does the console say?

Comment: Hello John, console says nothing (DreamWeaver) 
When I inspect the web page and go to the "time" div tag, it is empty.

Comment: You have a leading space in the `src` attribute of your `<script>` tag. Is your Javascript loading properly?

Comment: `document.write` will destroy the contents your page, so that div is gone by the time you try to reference it.

Comment: Where is `dtString` defined/set?

Comment: Here is the website.http://www.computing.northampton.ac.uk/~13422770/assign1/index.html

The only java script it has is the code I've posted on top.

Comment: dtString is defined in the java script file, I presume by the looks of the code (sorry, i've started java script), hence the website only containing html and css

Comment: @PatrickQ You're correct! It's not declared nor is it initiated!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Patrick I realized that I did not declare dtString.

Instead of complicating things the simple solution was to copy the text in to a div tag, which I had found useful since it displayed the date and time.

```
                    <div id="date">
                       <script>
                            now = new Date();

                            localtime = now.toString();
                            globaltime = now.toGMTString();

                            document.write(localtime);

                            hours = now.getHours();
                            mins = now.getMinutes();
                            secs = now.getSeconds();

                            document.write ("<font size = '+1'>");
                            document.write(hours + ":" + mins +":" + secs);
                            document.write("</font>");

                        </script>


                    </div>
```